# Rich faces tree refresh selected node

Tags: java, tree, richfaces, seam

Can someone provide me a working example of rich tree which refreshes it's nodes, when there is a new child added or removed. It should be done using ajaxKeys attribute, but I can't find any working examples on it.

Thanks in advance